Does every non-trivial path in the plane pass through either a rational point or an irrational point?
Does every non-trivial path in $\mathbb{R}^2$ pass through a point of $(\mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{Q}) \cup (\mathbb{I} \times \mathbb{I})$?
The topology is the usual Euclidean.
My intuition says yes, but no idea how to show that. I use this as part of a counterexample to another problem.
Edit after correct answer:
This problem is equivalent to whether $(\mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{I}) \cup (\mathbb{I} \times \mathbb{Q})$ is totally path-disconnected. The accepted answer can also be used to show the stronger statement that $(\mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{I}) \cup (\mathbb{I} \times \mathbb{Q})$ is totally separated (which implies totally disconnected).

Very recently, here it was shown that $(\mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{I}) \cup (\mathbb{I} \times \mathbb{Q})$ is in fact zero-dimensional. (I guess that $\mathbb{I}$ denotes the set of irrationals?)

@Ulli Yes, by $\mathbb{I}$ I mean irrationals.

Write $X$ for your set of rational points union irrational points. Yes, every nonconstant path in $\mathbb{R}^2$ hits $X$.
Note that any "rational line" $t\mapsto (q_1 + q_2t, q_3 +  q_4t)$ (where $q_i \in \mathbb{Q} \setminus\{0\}$) has image in $X$.
Assuming your path $\gamma\colon[0,1]\to \mathbb{R^2}$ is nonconstant, assume $\gamma(a) \neq \gamma(b)$. Then there is a rational line separating $\gamma(a)$ and $\gamma(b)$, so by the intermediate value theorem, $\gamma$ must hit that rational line, and must thereby hit $X$.
To produce such a rational line separating your two points $\gamma(a)$ and $\gamma(b)$, choose close enough rational approximations for each point, then use the perpendicular bisector of the rational approximations.

Very nice use of IVT!

That seems to do it. There's something unintuitive to me that the rational lines fit into $X$, although I can see it now. I'd try with vertical and horizontal lines, and see that they do not fit, and that seems unencouraging. But in fact they are the only ones that do not fit.

I believe that the definition of "rational line" could allow $q_1$ and $q_3$ to be $0$.  In fact, you could require one of them to be $0$.  I agree it is key the other two not be $0$.
